# Грамматическая основа предложения "До свидания, журавли"

Tags: синтаксис

По просьбе **Элен** дублирую свой вопрос-комментарий из соседней темы :
имеется ли грамматическая основа в предложении "До свидания, журавли".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этикетные формулы, или междометные предложения, занимают промежуточное положение между односоставными неполными и нечленимыми предложениями.

Чаще всего междометное предложение называют нечленимым предложением=словом-предложением, и тогда у него нет грамматической основы, в нём нет членов предложения вообще, оно не несёт информации, только выражает эмоцию,выполняет коммуникативную функцию.

Предложения, образованные  этикетными междометиями из существительных,  могут быть сопоставимы с различными типами односоставных предложений. Некоторые из таких междометных конструкций являются результатом эллипсиса глагольной части определенно-личных предложений : до свидания = расстаемся до следующего свидания, удачи= желаю удачи и т.д. Тогда мы говорим, что это предложение с опущенной грамматической основой. Так что её всё равно нет, во всяком случае при разборе по членам предложения не подчёркиваем вообще или подчёркиваем как дополнение.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за интересную информацию, новую для меня.

Comment: Людмила, а источник текста? Вы?

Comment: Скорее всего, предмет нашего внимания является не предложением, а высказыванием. Некоторые словесные конструкции "
 не имеют грамматической
основы (главные члены не
представлены словесно, нет и их
синтаксических позиций) – это не
предложения. Такие построения в
науке называют высказываниями." < http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200501306>

Comment: И Вам спасибо за вклад в мое образование (не шучу!)

Comment: behemothus, источник ЭТОГО текста я, а информация такого рода доступна любому интересующемуся, искать не буду, я со студенческой скамьи помню, а Вы посмотрите нечленимые предложения, этикетные формы. По-моему, сейчас это называют, как сказал grumant, высказываниями, а не предложениями, у них нет основы и вообще члены предложения там не ищут, они нечленимы.

Answer (score 0):

Что является предметом речи в данном предложении? О чем говорится? О "до свидания". Значит, это и есть грамматическая основа предложения. 
   Правда, не знаю, может ли грамматичесчкая основа подразумеваться. Если да, то можно рассуждать так, что это неполное предложение, где пропущены восстанавливаемые по смыслу слова "Мы расстаемся до следующего свидания, журавли".

Comment: Мы имеем обращение 'журавли' и пожелание 'до свидания'. Грамматической основы нет. Пожелания могут быть разными, например :
Счастья вам, женщины! (Т.Лазарева, студия ОСП)))

Comment: Спасибо за интересное замечание, но никак не могу согласиться, что в предложении может не быть грамматической основы. Нет основы - нет и мысли. Но мысль ведь есть в любом предложении, даже если мы переспрашиваем кого-то, не расслышав: "А?" Как с этим быть? Мне не приходилось встречаться с материалами, где говорилось бы о возможности отсутствия грамм. основы. Может, Вы знаете такие источники? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Виктор, Вы переводите вопрос в философскую плоскость. Мы так никогда не договоримся. Потому, что придётся давать ответы на вопросы "А что такое предложение?" и "Есть ли мысль у междометия?".  
С нелегкой руки одного участника форма мой вопрос, который относился к предложениям с опущенной или подразумевающейся основой, превратился в очередные поиски вечного двигателя.